# VS how to avoid release again when deploy a .Net Framework application?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, release, publish

I want to encrypt the exe program and then package it to generate an installer. But when I publish the project, it will release again to overwrite my encryption process.
I didn't find a setting to cancel the release, so is there a way to deal with this, besides implementing the installer yourself?

Comment: Are you saying, without actually saying, that you are using ClickOnce to deploy your app? If so then maybe you could exclude the EXE and add the encrypted EXE under Application Files but they'd have to have different names and I'm not 100% sure it would work.

Comment: You may also be able to add a post-build event under Build Events to perform the encryption and then a publish operation performing a build would not be an issue.

Comment: @PeterSmith I use the publish function that comes with the right click of the VS project, so in addition to the settings, many steps cannot be intervened, such as it will auto release again that I asked about. So it will create a new exe difficult to exclude, and I can't add a post-build event, Of course it could be that I do not know how to do it :)

Comment: That publish function creates a ClickOnce installer, so you're using ClickOnce. The publish process is controlled by the settings on the Publish page of the project properties, which you should already be aware of because every developer should be taking a thorough look through the project properties in a very early, if not their first, project to see what is available and what can be modified. You add build events in the project properties too, which will be applied to every build, regardless of how it is initiated. If you take the time to explore then you won't always be in the dark.